# Combining Two Ranges in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to combine two ranges of a document and make it as another range.
I have used `Union` method. but its

```
wordrange2.Find.Execute ("years ")
Set range1 = wordobj.ActiveDocument.Range(0, wordrange2.Start)
Set range2 = wordobj.ActiveDocument.Range(wordrange2.End, wordobj.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1)
Set wordrange2 = Union(range1, range2)
```

in the last line, its saying

> type mismatch

`wordrange2` is a `Range` object, but it saying type mismatch

Comment: The `Union` method is not there for Word VBA object Model. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: use an array of ranges, like `rngArray = Array(range1, range2)` and work further with both element of array (separately).

Comment: @ siddhart rout:  I am trying to get a entire document Range without the word "years"

Comment: Just replace "years " with vbNullString?